# Forwarding traffic through an intermediate host to a VPN

Tags: networking, vpn, routing, openvpn, iptables

I have a somewhat unusual networking setup that I'm trying to get going, and I just can't seem to get the routing or the filtering right to make it work.

I have a subnet of client computers connected to a host which is internet connected. This host has an OpenVPN connection to a server. What I want to do is have all traffic from the client subnet route through the OpenVPN server. (for sake of simplicity I'll talk about a single client, I'm sure if I can get one going I can get all of them going)

```
----------------     -------------------------     --------------------
| client  eth0 |-----| eth1     host    tun0 |-----| tun0      server |
| 192.168.0.2  |     | 192.168.0.1  10.0.0.2 |     | 10.0.0.1         |
----------------     |      ppp0 - internet  |     | eth0 - internet  |
                     -------------------------     --------------------
```

So far, I've set up routes that allow the clients to talk to the server through the host, so 192.168.0.2 can ping 10.0.0.1 and vice-versa. I have set the default route on the client to send all traffic to 192.168.0.1 however a traceroute from the client to any internet IP shows it only going as far as 192.168.0.1 and stopping there. The intermediate host has no trouble accessing the internet, or the server.

client routing table:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
255.255.255.255 *               255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 eth0
10.0.0.0        192.168.0.1     255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 eth0
192.168.0.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth0
default         192.168.0.1     0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
```

intermediate host routing table:

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
255.255.255.255 *               255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 eth1
10.42.42.1      *               255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 tun0
10.42.42.0      10.42.42.1      255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 tun0
192.168.0.0     *               255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 eth1
default         *               0.0.0.0         U     0      0        0 ppp0
```

server routing table (anonymized)

```
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         xxx.xxx.xxx.1   0.0.0.0         UG    202    0        0 eth0
default         servername      0.0.0.0         UG    204    0        0 tun0
10.0.0.0        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     0      0        0 tun0
10.0.0.2        0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    0      0        0 tun0
192.168.0.0     10.0.0.2        255.255.255.0   UG    0      0        0 tun0
xxx.xxx.xxx.0   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U     202    0        0 eth0
xxx.xxx.xxx.1   0.0.0.0         255.255.255.255 UH    100    0        0 eth0
```

intermediate host iptables:

```
Chain INPUT (policy DROP 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
2719K  250M ACCEPT     all  --  eth1   any     anywhere             anywhere            
32859 2697K ACCEPT     all  --  lo     any     anywhere             anywhere            
 405K   37M ACCEPT     all  --  eth1   any     anywhere             anywhere            
 1398  134K ACCEPT     all  --  tun0   any     anywhere             anywhere            
 6420  900K ACCEPT     all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             ctstate RELATED,ESTABLISHED
    0     0 DROP       all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             ctstate INVALID
    0     0 ACCEPT     icmp --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             icmp echo-request ctstate NEW
    2   360 UDP        udp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             ctstate NEW
    0     0 TCP        tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             tcp flags:FIN,SYN,RST,ACK/SYN ctstate NEW
    2   360 REJECT     udp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
    0     0 REJECT     tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             reject-with tcp-reset
    0     0 REJECT     all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             reject-with icmp-proto-unreachable

Chain FORWARD (policy DROP 36 packets, 2256 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
    2   168 ACCEPT     all  --  eth1   tun0    anywhere             anywhere            
    2   168 ACCEPT     all  --  tun0   eth1    anywhere             anywhere            

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 1007K packets, 158M bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
 1021  113K ACCEPT     all  --  any    eth1    anywhere             anywhere             state RELATED,ESTABLISHED

Chain TCP (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         

Chain UDP (1 references)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination
```

server iptables:

```
Chain INPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
 240K   19M ACCEPT     all  --  lo     any     anywhere             anywhere            
    0     0 REJECT     all  --  any    any     anywhere             127.0.0.0/8          reject-with icmp-port-unreachable
1831K  432M ACCEPT     all  --  tun0   any     anywhere             anywhere            
4043K 1404M ACCEPT     all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
 3928  212K ACCEPT     tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:smtp
   90  4516 ACCEPT     tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:urd
  315 16852 ACCEPT     tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:submission
  116  5848 ACCEPT     tcp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             tcp dpt:pop3s
 3461  396K ACCEPT     udp  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             udp dpt:openvpn
 4347  208K ACCEPT     icmp --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere             icmp echo-request
1475K  462M DROP       all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            

Chain FORWARD (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
36055 3583K ACCEPT     all  --  tun0   eth0    anywhere             anywhere            
16333 3770K ACCEPT     all  --  eth0   tun0    anywhere             anywhere             state RELATED,ESTABLISHED
    4   304 DROP       all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere            

Chain OUTPUT (policy ACCEPT 0 packets, 0 bytes)
 pkts bytes target     prot opt in     out     source               destination         
5678K 1392M ACCEPT     all  --  any    any     anywhere             anywhere
```

Now the "gotchas":

- the intermediate host is a weird IOT device running Ubuntu. I have
  full root access on it, can add and delete routes, and can play with
  iptables, but I can't do things like install kernel modules or new applications as the main filesystem is read-only (I can however run scripts at boot from the writable home directory).
- the intermediate host "ppp0" is a cellular data connection, and the device doesn't play nice with other connection methods, I also don't want to have to pay my provider a monthly fee (among the highest cellular rates in the world here!) for yet another cellular connection to this site for the other devices, so changing the network topology here is unrealistic.

Overall, I suspect my real issue is iptables, but I'm unsure as to where or what.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: (ipv4) forwarding sysctl

Comment: also snat/masquerade on the "intermediate" host or add route for the subnet on the server

Comment: @TomYan I don't believe I should need to nat or masquerade on the intermediate host, because the end server is handling that. I've always been taught that double nat is a bad thing. Additionally, I can't do that because it requires adding a kernel module which I can't do on that host. I believe the route is properly added on the server as the server can ping the subnet, and vice-versa.

Comment: @TomYan Can you tell me more about what you mean by forwarding sysctl?

Comment: If you can access the internet *via the VPN* from the intermediate host, the cause of the problem might be you are doing snat/masquerade only for the VPN IP subnet.

Comment: You literally just need to google `ipv4 sysctl forward`: https://linuxconfig.org/how-to-turn-on-off-ip-forwarding-in-linux. Make sure it is enabled on both the intermediate host and the server.

Comment: @Tom Yan I have double checked and both hosts show net.ipv4.ip_forward = 1. Your point about masquerading only the VPN subnet was valid though, so I changed iptables to masquerade the internal subnet too. Unfortunately I'm still not getting anywhere. traceroutes from the client still die at the host.

Comment: Ahh, looks like you don't use the VPN for Internet on the intermediate host and only want to do that on the client. In that case you need to do policy routing.

Comment: @Tom Yan I am trying to use the vpn for internet on the intermediate host, but it seems to be ignoring the instruction to do so. The openvpn ccd file for the host has push "redirect-gateway def1" in it, and the conf file has redirect-gateway def1 in it. But when I traceroute from that host, it seems to go straight out the cellular connection bypassing the vpn except when I try to connect to a host on the VPN subnet.